# Poisson process with time exponentially distributed

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

While studying Poisson processes, I have found a problem I can't solve:

> Two people, A and B, arrive at a bank and wait to be attended. A and B are in the waiting queue and A is before B. The workers attend the customers according to a Poisson process of parameter λ<sub>w</sub>. A and B are willing to wait, respectively, a time T<sub>A</sub> and T<sub>B</sub> before going away. T<sub>A</sub> and T<sub>B</sub> are exponentially distributed with parameters λ<sub>A</sub> and λ<sub>B</sub>.
>
> What is the probability that the person B is attended before he or she leaves?

How can we calculate the answer?

Comment: What have you tried?  WIthout showing some work, and saying where you got stuck, it just looks like you are trying to get somebody to solve a homework problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the patience times apply equally whether a customer is in service or waiting for service, the time customer A is in the system is exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda_A+\lambda_W$. Hence the probability that customer B is attended is
$$
\frac{\lambda_A+\lambda_W}{\lambda_A+\lambda_W+\lambda_B}.
$$